# hMailServer password hashing

Tags: mysql, hash, hmail-server

I have installed hMailServer on Windows and linked it to MySQL. While I am creating email accounts, passwords that I am entering while creation are hashed before inserted the database.(I do not which type of an algorithm is used while hashing. Documentation does not help). So now, I want to switch hashing off or use another well-known algorithm like md5. Even though I am making changes to hmailServer.ini file and set preferredHashAlgorithm to 0 (no hashing), but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Only hMailServer Administrator Users Password is hashed as MD5 but not the database users (regardless which DB).

Database passwords are always hashed as Blowfish Hash.

Check this Article regarding hMailServers DB-Password hashes:
https://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=33793

Answer (score 0):

The hmailServer version 5.6.7 use md5 to hash both the Administrator and the hMailServer database password.

When you make any change to the hmailServer.ini file, you nead to restart the hmailServer service.